# Должен ли iPad Pro отображать мобильную версию сайта?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, media-queries

Заказчик тестирует верстку, требует, что бы на iPad Pro отображалась мобильная версия. Я использую систему сетки Bootstrap. Но разрешение экрана iPad Pro 1024px, а это больше чем 768px, т.е. должна отображаться десктопная версия?

Answer (score 0):

1)

- `max-width: 767px` (мобильная)
- `max-width: 991px` (планшет, но часто не заморачиваютя и здесь тоже
  мобильная версия сайта)
- `min-width: 992px` (desctop)

2) Нужно копать в сторону `user agent`.

Если у вас сайт на `wordpress`, то у `wordpress` есть встроенный `mobile detect`.

PHP код: (может быть написан, к примеру, в файле index.php)

```
if ( wp_is_mobile ) {} else {}
```

Это условие можно засунуть вообще в тег `<body>` и если `wp_is_mobile`, то добавить `<body>` класс `is-mobile`, иначе класс `is-desctop`.

А дальше от этого класса писать медиа-запросы.

Я не говорю, что это правильно, но, возможно, это поможет.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp >

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
}

html {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;
}

.header {
  background-color: #9933cc;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  background-color: #33b5e5;
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}

.menu li:hover {
  background-color: #0099cc;
}

.aside {
  background-color: #33b5e5;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}

.footer {
  background-color: #0099cc;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 15px;
}

/* For desktop: */
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* For mobile phones: */
  [class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h1>Chania</h1>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3 menu">
    <ul>
    <li>The Flight</li>
    <li>The City</li>
    <li>The Island</li>
    <li>The Food</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col-6">
    <h1>The City</h1>
    <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-3 right">
    <div class="aside">
      <h2>What?</h2>
      <p>Chania is a city on the island of Crete.</p>
      <h2>Where?</h2>
      <p>Crete is a Greek island in the Mediterranean Sea.</p>
      <h2>How?</h2>
      <p>You can reach Chania airport from all over Europe.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how the content respond to the resizing.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```